# Return content type

Tags: 7, search

With core search, in [`template_preprocess_search_result()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7.x) I could access `$vars['result']['type']`. Switching over to Search API Solr, how can I access node type and send it to the theme? Content type is being indexed, but I'm not sure how to return it with the result.

Comment: I think you can implement hook_apachesolr_search_result_alter() to have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Search API pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_page), I switched to [`template_preprocess_search_api_page_result(&$vars)`](http://www.rit.edu/drupal/api/drupal/sites!all!modules!search_api_page!search_api_page.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_api_page_result/7.41), and can achieve this by getting the nid.

```
$node = node_load($vars['id']);
$vars['pass_to_template'] = node_type_get_name($node);
```